# Invalid initial heap size: -Xms128M -Xmx512M -Xss1024K -Dlog4j.debug ...?

Tags: java, windows, 32bit-64bit, windbg

My setup:

- Windows 64 bits
- Java application loading 32 bits native modules
- Can be run fine outside the debugger using the 32bits Java (jdk1.6.0_29) with the following command line - "-Xms128M -Xmx512M -Xss1024K -Dlog4j.debug ..." (trimmed for brevity)

The problem starts if I want to debug the native modules. So, I fire my windbg 64 bits using the following powershell command line:

```
windbg -logo c:\dumps\dbg.log -QY -awow64exts -c "!sw;bu $entry;g;g" "$env:JAVA_HOME\bin\java.exe" $Params
```

Where `$Params` are exactly the same params used to run it outside the debugger.

The debugger starts, but the sessions is very short:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin\java.exe" "-Xms128M -Xmx512M -Xss1024K -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../conf/log4j.xml -Ddozer.configuration=file:../conf/config.properties -jar bootstrapper.jar com.shunra.bootstrapper.guice.Bootstrapper"
Symbol search path is: C:\dev\shunra\DriverProxy\CloudAPI\CLOUDAPI\Profile\Stratus;C:\dev\shunra\DriverProxy\LocalDriverProxy\Profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\cJSON\lib\win32\Profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\curl\lib\win32\Profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\DataStruct\lib\win32\profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\GraphSetup\lib\win32\profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\multikey_lookup\lib\win32\profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\ShunraAPICommon\lib\win32\Profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\ShunraAPIEmulation\lib\win32\Profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\ShunraAPIParsers\lib\win32\Profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\ShunraAPIRest\lib\win32\Profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\ShunraUtils\lib\win32\profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\ShunraXercesUtils\lib\win32\profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\SNetXMLBuilder\lib\win32\profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\StormEngine\lib\win32\profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\xerces-c-2.80\Build\Win32\VC10\Profile;C:\dev\shunra\SharedModules\XMLControl\lib\win32\profile;srv*Z:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00000000`00400000 00000000`00424000   java.exe
ModLoad: 00000000`77540000 00000000`776e9000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`77720000 00000000`778a0000   ntdll32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`74da0000 00000000`74ddf000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`74d40000 00000000`74d9c000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`74d30000 00000000`74d38000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll
(684.e30): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
Processing initial command '!sw;bu LocalDriverProxy!Java_com_shunra_vcat_core_emulation_LocalDriverProxy_StartEmulation;g;g'
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00000000`775ecb60 cc              int     3
0:000> !sw;bu LocalDriverProxy!Java_com_shunra_vcat_core_emulation_LocalDriverProxy_StartEmulation;g;g
Switched to 32bit mode
ModLoad: 76e60000 76f7f000   WOW64_IMAGE_SECTION
ModLoad: 00000000`75300000 00000000`75410000   WOW64_IMAGE_SECTION
ModLoad: 00000000`76e60000 00000000`76f7f000   NOT_AN_IMAGE
ModLoad: 00000000`77190000 00000000`7728a000   NOT_AN_IMAGE
ModLoad: 00000000`75300000 00000000`75410000   C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`752b0000 00000000`752f7000   C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`769a0000 00000000`76a40000   C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`76710000 00000000`767bc000   C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`76390000 00000000`763a9000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`75410000 00000000`75500000   C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`74e00000 00000000`74e60000   C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`74df0000 00000000`74dfc000   C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
(684.e30): WOW64 breakpoint - code 4000001f (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
ModLoad: 74860000 748ac000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`7c340000 00000000`7c396000   c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6d8a0000 00000000`6db4f000   c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`76610000 00000000`76710000   C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`76c20000 00000000`76cb0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`74ee0000 00000000`74eea000   C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`76190000 00000000`7622d000   C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`747e0000 00000000`74812000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WINMM.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`76af0000 00000000`76b50000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`76b50000 00000000`76c1c000   C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`74860000 00000000`748ac000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6d850000 00000000`6d85c000   c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\bin\verify.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6d3d0000 00000000`6d3ef000   c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\bin\java.dll
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xa:
00000000`775915da c3              ret
```

Finito! Java terminates printing this short message in the console window:

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms128M -Xmx512M -Xss1024K -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../conf/log4j.xml -Ddozer.configuration=file
:../conf/config.properties -jar bootstrapper.jar com.shunra.bootstrapper.guice.Bootstrapper
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

**EDIT**

Following some comments below, I tend to think I have a problem with me powershell script.

Indeed, as Jon Skeet suggested I have tried to run a HelloWorld java app from within the debugger with the same -XYZ params and it worked. And then came a comment by Codo, which made me think something is rotten with my powershell code.

Here it is:

```
$env:JAVA_HOME='c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29'
$Params="-Xms128M -Xmx512M -Xss1024K -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../conf/log4j.xml -Ddozer.configuration=file:../conf/config.properties -jar bootstrapper.jar com.shunra.bootstrapper.guice.Bootstrapper"
windbg -logo c:\dumps\dbg.log -QY -awow64exts -c "!sw;g;g" "$env:JAVA_HOME\bin\java.exe" $Params
```

The `$Params` seems to be passed as a single string to the java process. OK, so I expand it:

```
windbg -logo c:\dumps\dbg.log -QY -awow64exts -c "!sw;g;g" "$env:JAVA_HOME\bin\java.exe" -Xms128M -Xmx512M -Xss1024K -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../conf/log4j.xml -Ddozer.configuration=file:../conf/config.properties -jar bootstrapper.jar com.shunra.bootstrapper.guice.Bootstrapper
```

Now I get a different fatal error printed out by java:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /debug
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .debug
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: .debug.  Program will exit.
```

What does it want from my life?

**EDIT2**

Changed the command line as per Codo's suggestion:

```
windbg -logo c:\dumps\dbg.log -QY -awow64exts -c "!sw;g;g" "$env:JAVA_HOME\bin\java.exe" -Xms128M -Xmx512M -Xss1024K -Dlog4j.debug=true -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../conf/log4j.xml -Ddozer.configuration=file:../conf/config.properties -jar bootstrapper.jar com.shunra.bootstrapper.guice.Bootstrapper
```

Now the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /debug=true
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .debug=true
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: .debug=true.  Program will exit.
```

Which means the `-Dlog4j.debug=true` is interpreted as a class name, rather than JVM option. I do not understand what's going on.

Comment: Can you start the JVM with those memory arguments running just a tiny test app?

Comment: Do you mean inside the debugger? Because outside the debugger it works with exactly the same params, my post mentions it.

Comment: Yes, inside the debugger. Basically, try to remove as much as you can from the problem.

Comment: Your parameters probably have too many double quotes so the Java VM doesn't properly split them. Or the debugger passes them on differently so that the same effect occurs.

Comment: Thank you Jon, thank you Codo. You got me closer to understanding it, but I still have problems. Please, see the EDIT.

Comment: It still seems as if you're parameters are incorrectly split. Can you try to use `-Dlog4j.debug=true` instead of `-Dlog4j.debug`. And can you try to omit it altogether. If my speculation is correct, you would see a different error message.

Comment: My current conclusion - as opposed to yours - is that `-Dlog4j.debug=true` gets split into two parts (likely `-Dlog4j` and `debug=true`). And since the second part doesn't start with a hyphen, it's not interpreted as an option for the VM but rather as the argument specifying the main class. I don't understand how this happens either.

Comment: Did you try putting `-Dlog4j.debug=true` in quotes?